# Equivalent Definition of Integrality Over a Ring Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Take the standard definition of integrality over a ring as follows:

$1.)$ Let $B$ be a ring, and $A$ its subring. An element $b \in B$ is integral over $A$ if there exists a monic (non-trivial) polynomial $f \in A[X]$ such that $f(b)=0$

Equivalently, there is also the following definition:

$2.)$ There exists a subring $C \subset B$ containing $A$ and $b$, which is an $A$-module of finite type.

Now, aside from this there are of course other definitions, but I am looking at the proof that $2.) \implies 1.)$. I will begin the proof as I have it, and will stop when I arrive at my problem.

Let $C= c_1 A + ... c_m A$. Then for each $1 \leq i \leq m$, $bc_i = \sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij} c_j$ for some $a_{ij} \in A$. So $\sum_{j=1}^m (\delta_{ij}b-a_{ij})c_j = 0$. Then use this to construct the $m \times m$ matrix, $M = (\delta_{ij}b-a_{ij})$ so $M$ looks as such:

\begin{pmatrix}
  b-a_{11} & -a_{12} & \cdots & -a_{1m} \\
  -a_{21} & b-a_{22} & \cdots &- a_{2m} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  -a_{m1} & -a_{m2} & \cdots & b-a_{mm} 
 \end{pmatrix}

Notice that $det(M) = f(b)$ for some $f\in A[X]$, further $f$ is monic. Then $det(M) I_{m \times m} = adj(M) \times M$, where $I_{m \times m}$ is the identity matrix of degree $m$. Denote by $\psi$, the $j^{th}$ column of $M$.

And this is where my issue is. The next line of the proof is as so:

$\textbf{Now we get $M \psi = 0$ (the $0$ column vector of size $m$).}$

How can you conclude this? The rest of the proof is straight forward from this (using $det(M) I_{m \times m} \psi = adj(M) \times M \psi$ to determine that $det(M)=0$, and hence $f(b) = 0$, thus $b$ is integral over $A$). But I fail to see how one can simply jumpt to the conclusion that $M \psi = 0$. Any assistance would be largely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you select $\psi$ to be a column of $M$. Surely you should have
$$\psi=\pmatrix{c_1\\c_2\\\cdots\\c_n}$$
since $M$ is created specifically so that $M\psi=0$.

Comment: So then $M \psi=\pmatrix{\sum_j (\delta_{1j}b-a_{ij})c_j\\\sum_j (\delta_{2j}b-a_{2j})c_j\\\vdots\\\sum_j (\delta_{mj}b-a_{mj})c_j}$ which by definition gives $M \psi=\pmatrix{ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0}$?

Comment: I'm skipping an intermediate step, but this would ultimately be what appears in the final step of this matrix multiplication. This clarifies everything. Thank you